# Uncaught Error: Class 'tool\Mobile_detect' not found PHP

Tags: php

I am using namespace for my php code. However, it gets problem while loading from vendor

header.php

```
//define mobile detect
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/vendor/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib/Mobile_Detect.php');
```

tool.php

```
namespace tool;

class main{
    function getPlatform(){
        global $conn;
        $detect = new Mobile_detect;
        $platform = "desktop";
        if($detect->isMobile()){
            $platform = "mobile";
        }
        else if($detect->isTablet()){
            $platform = "tablet";
        }
        $os = 'global';
        if($detect->isiOS()){
            $os = 'ios'; //because we need special treat for this
        }
        else if($detect->isAndroidOS()){
            $os = 'android';
        }
        $object = array();
        $object['platform'] = $platform; //set into global var
        $object['os'] = $os;
        return $object;
    }
}
```

If I do not use namespace, it works without problem. Using namespace leads to this error. How to load other function from vendor to our namespace.

Comment: What is the namespace of Mobile_detect?

Comment: there is no detailed information from the page http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: Ok, so this line `$detect = new Mobile_detect;` will be `$detect = new \Mobile_detect;` making PHP look for the class in global namespace.

Comment: great! anyway I have one more problem with new \Google_Service_Oauth2($client); error shows => Undefined type 'Google_Service_Oauth2' intelephense(1009)

Comment: I have no clue about your project structure and files, so won't be able to help. This seems to be a different question for which you can make a new post.

Comment: okay, anyway thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome, appreciate your feedback.